# Implementation-specific constants in service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, interface

I have an ASP.Net Web Forms project, which is built as (among other things) a user interface to a CRM web service.

I have an interface, `IMembershipService`, which exposes a number of methods for purchasing different kinds of subscriptions to a service. The concrete implementation of this, `SpecificMemberService`, will abstract a number of web service calls to a third-party CRM system.

The concrete implementation requires that different 'subscription levels' be passed to it as specific 4-character string codes. Currently, I have defined the following in my service layer:

```
public static class MemberTypes
{
    public const string Basic = "MEM1";
    public const string Extra = "MEM2";
    public const string Professional = "MEM3";
}
```

However, these codes are specific to the concrete class `SpecificMemberService` and - as such - shouldn't really be independent of it as they currently are. How can I expose strongly-typed  `MemberType` codes to my web application, which are constant with respect to a *concrete implementation* of `IMembershipService`?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether your system and the backend system have the same or different _concept_ of a member type? I mean do you expect that an other concrete member service will have different codes for the member types, or even different number of member types or even mmore complex descriptors of the member types (eg. with multiple dimensions?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a MemberType inferface.  Add a `GetMemberTypes` method to your service Interface that exposes a Collection of `IMemberType`.

```
public interface IMemberType {      
    public string Name { get; set; } // i.e. "Professional"
    public string Code { get; set; } // i.e. "MEM3"
}

public void ClientCode() {

    // Instantiate a concrete service (calling a factory would be even better).
    IMembershipService service = new MembershipService();

    // Get the list of MemberTypes exposed by the concrete MembershipService.
    Collecton<IMemberTypes> types = service.GetMemberTypes();

    // Subscribe to service defined in IMembershipService with "Professional" level, if possible.
    foreach (IMemeberType type in types) {
        if ((type.Name == "Professional"))
            service.SubscribeToAwesomeService(type.Code);
    }
}
```

Expose "Professional" as a Constant or Enum for bonus points.